# empty character literal in stringified block

Tags: c++, clang, language-lawyer, c-preprocessor, c++03

To simplify writing of SQL queries in C++ I use macro

```
#define SQL(...) #__VA_ARGS__
```

It works fine, except whenever empty string literal comes up (in something like

```
SQL(select * from foo where bar = '')
```

), clang (and no other compiler) gives warning

```
warning: empty character constant [-Winvalid-pp-token]
```

Is what I am doing a gross hack (that I am keeping anyway because it allows multi-line sql statements to be readable) that violates standard or is clang overly critical here (the character literal is not appearing in preprocessor directive)?

**Edit:** Forgot to mention that not all of our platforms support C++11, so we can't use raw string literals. We are likely stuck with VisualC++ 9.0 for some years and Gcc 4.6-somesnapshot with probably fewer, but still years. The hack also predates C++11.

Comment: Its a gross hack :o) What I often do is this: `std::ostringstream sql; sql << "select * from table"; sql << " where id = '"; sql << id; sql << "'"; mysql_execute(&mysql, sql.str().c_str());`

Comment: @Galik: Don't dare to mention string operations with sql. That should be firing offence! The hack I am talking about is only about replacing double quotes with suitable multi-line construct because our SQL statements often have upwards of 30 lines when properly broken up and indented for readability.

Comment: it's easy to have readable multi-line sql statements if you split up the string literals - ie. `"select *" " from foo" " where bar = ''"` can be split up over 3 lines (and indented), but still counts as only one string literal.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: Yes. Except, well, imagine you have statement over 30 lines long and you need to change it which involves removing, adding, joining and splitting lines. Adding and removing the quotes all around is pain in the arse not to mention you no longer get autoindent and parenthesis matching from most editors.

Comment: @JanHudec Can you elaborate a bit why string operations on SQL should be a firing offence (or share a relevant link)? I admit I am totally outside the DB field, but I'd like to broaden my horizons.

Comment: @Angew: Because trying to ensure the inserted parameters don't contain any special characters or are properly quoted is error-prone and mistakes lead to SQL injection vulnerabilities if the parameters come from user and difficult to diagnose bugs otherwise. All databases support parameter binding which takes care of correct quoting, plus generally such statement is parsed once and can be run with multiple parameter substitutions yielding significant time saving as the query does not need to be re-parsed and especially re-optimized.

Comment: @JanHudec Aha, OK, thanks. So without the `id` part and any flow control, just inserting string literals one after the other, I assume it would be OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing is a gross hack, and if you are compiling with Clang (and other modern compilers) but have no need to support older compilers, there's a much easier way: raw string literals.

```
std::string query = R"sql(
  select * from foo where bar = ''
)sql";
```

This even allows you to embed quotes and backslashes in the query without escaping, if you want to.

For reference, raw string literals have been supported since Clang 3.0, GCC 4.5, and Visual Studio 2013.

From a language-lawyer view, Clang is generous in allowing your code to compile at all. It is not valid. C++14 2.2 says that in phase 3 (macro substitution happens in phase 4), the source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and sequences of whitespace.

2.5 lists the preprocessing-token grammar production. There is exactly one option there that starts with a single quote, which is character-literal. Character literals are defined in 2.14.3 as

```
character-literal:
    ' c-char-sequence '
    <prefixed versions>

c-char-sequence:
    c-char
    c-char-sequence c-char

c-char:
    any member of the source character set except
        the single-quote ' , backslash \, or new-line character
    escape-sequence
    universal-character-name
```

Note that c-char-sequence consists of at least one c-char, and c-char cannot be a single quote. Therefore, no grammar production in C++ matches `''`. This sequence cannot appear in a conforming program outside of something bigger (like a string literal).

The macro process does not work on the character level, after all, it works on the token level. Everything needs to be tokenized first.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention it has to compile down to Visual Studio 2008 and Gcc 4.5.0. Oh, and the question is tagged language-lawyer.

Comment: Added the lawyery stuff.